# Scroll function doesn't work on firefox

Tags: javascript, jquery, firefox, scroll, mousewheel

i made an increment class function on a li list on mousewheel event, it's working well on Chrome and Safari but on firefox the function only scroll down i can't scroll back. How can i fix it?
this is my actual code:

```js
var scrollable = $('ul li').length - 1,
  count = 0,
  allowTransition = true;
$('body').bind('wheel DOMMouseScroll', function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();

  if (allowTransition) {

    allowTransition = false;
    if (e.originalEvent.wheelDelta / 120 > 0) {
      if (scrollable >= count && count > 0) {
        $('.active').removeClass('active').prev().addClass('active');
        count--;
      } else {
        allowTransition = true;
        return false;
      }
    } else {
      if (scrollable > count) {
        $('.active').removeClass('active').next().addClass('active');

        count++;
      } else {
        allowTransition = true;
        return false;
      }
    }
    setTimeout(function() {
      allowTransition = true;
    }, 1000);
  }
})
```

```css
body {
  overflow: hidden;
}
ul li {
  height: 20px;
  width: 20px;
  background: blue;
  margin: 5px;
  list-style: none
}
ul li.active {
  background: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<ul>
  <li class="active"></li>
  <li></li>
  <li></li>
  <li></li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firefox doesn't have the `wheelDelta` property, so the line

```
if (e.originalEvent.wheelDelta / 120 > 0) {`
```

line will always return `false`, and the code that does the scroll-up is inside that `if` statement.

> In Firefox you can use the [wheel](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/wheel) event, which have the `deltaY` property (also standard in Chrome 31 [2013]).

This change to your `if` statement will fix your problem:

```
if (e.originalEvent.wheelDelta / 120 > 0 || e.originalEvent.deltaY < 0) {
```

According to the [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WheelEvent/deltaY), the `deltaY` property is compatible in latest versions of chrome and firefox and also in IE9.

```js
$(function(){
    var scrollable = $('ul li').length - 1,
      count = 0,
      allowTransition = true;
    $('body').bind('wheel', function(e) {
      e.preventDefault();

      if (allowTransition) {

        allowTransition = false;
        if (e.originalEvent.wheelDelta / 120 > 0 || e.originalEvent.deltaY < 0) {
          if (scrollable >= count && count > 0) {
            $('.active').removeClass('active').prev().addClass('active');
            count--;
          } else {
            allowTransition = true;
            return false;
          }
        } else {
          if (scrollable > count) {
            $('.active').removeClass('active').next().addClass('active');

            count++;
          } else {
            allowTransition = true;
            return false;
          }
        }
        setTimeout(function() {
          allowTransition = true;
        }, 1000);
      }
    });
});
```

```css
body {
  overflow: hidden;
}
ul li {
  height: 20px;
  width: 20px;
  background: blue;
  margin: 5px;
  list-style: none
}
ul li.active {
  background: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<ul>
  <li class="active"></li>
  <li></li>
  <li></li>
  <li></li>
</ul>
```